# java code not providing output

Tags: java, system.out

I'm taking a class on Java and the code is submitted to myprogramminglab.com. My assignment asks the following:

Design a class  named  Person with fields for holding a person's name , address, and
telephone number (all as Strings ). Write a constructor  that initializes  all of these
values , and mutator and accessor methods  for every field.

Next, design a class  named  Customer, which inherits from the Person class . The Customer
class  should have a String  field for the customer number and a boolean  field indicating
whether  the customer wishes to be on a mailing list. Write a constructor  that
initializes  these values  and the appropriate mutator and accessor methods  for
the class 's fields.

Demonstrate the Customer class  in a program  that prompts the user to enter values 
for the customer's name , address, phone number, and customer number, and then
asks the user whether  or not the customer wants to recieve mail. Use this information
to create a customer object  and then print its information.

Put all of your classes in the same file. To do this, do not declare  them public. 
Instead, simply write:

class  Person { ... }
class  Customer { ... }

Where I am stuck is I am getting a logical error and there is no output, not even with the `System.out` I've been poring over my code and I don't know what I am missing. Can someone point me in the right direction? Below is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Person{
private String name, address, phoneNumber;

public Person(String name, String address, String phoneNumber){
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
    this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
}

public void setName(String n){
    name=n;
}

public void setAddress(String a){
    address=a;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String p){
    phoneNumber=p;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}

public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return phoneNumber;
}

}

class Customer extends Person{
private String customerNumber;
private boolean mailList;

public Customer(String name, String address, String phoneNumber, String customerNumber, boolean m){
    super(name,address,phoneNumber);
    this.customerNumber=customerNumber;
    mailList=m;
}

public void setCustomerNumber(String cust){
    customerNumber=cust;
}

public void setMailList(boolean mail){
    mailList=mail;
}

public String getCustomerNumber(){
    return customerNumber;
}

public boolean getMailList(){
    return mailList;
}
}

class CustomerDemo{

public static void main (String[] args){

    String name, address, phoneNumber,customerNumber,decision;
    boolean mailList;

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter·name·of·customer:");
    name=input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter address of customer:");
    address=input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter phone number of customer:");
    phoneNumber=input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter customer number:");
    customerNumber=input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter yes/no -- does the customer want to receive mail?:");
    decision=input.nextLine();
    mailList=decision.equals("yes");

    Customer cust=new Customer(name, address, phoneNumber,customerNumber,mailList);

    System.out.println("Customer: ");
    System.out.println("Name: " + cust.getName());
    System.out.println("Address: " + cust.getAddress());
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " +cust.getPhoneNumber());
    System.out.println("Customer Number: " + cust.getCustomerNumber());
    System.out.println("Receive Mail?: " + cust.getMailList());
}
}
```

Comment: This works for me using Eclipse.  I have a file *CustomerDemo.java* containing all of the above code.

Comment: Have you compiled your code? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: My guess is its a problem with MyProgrammingLab.

Comment: Thanks guys for looking at it. This is one of my pet peeves about MyProgrammingLab....